# undo changes on git branch

Tags: git

I created and switched to a new branch and made some changes that haven't been commited.
How do I return to the state of my last commit?
I used

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

but all the changed files are still present

edit;
after running the above and then git status it says "nothing added to commit but untracked files present".
I thought using git reset...would get rid of all the changes

Comment: git reset --hard HEAD works well for me (git version 1.7.6) - whether the changes are local or in the staging area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git clean` removes all files (recursively) that are not under version control, starting from the current directory.

See the [git clean docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways work for me:

```
git clean
git reset --hard HEAD  #reset all
```

or

```
git checkout file_I_want_discard_my_change
```

Comment: Don't you need `--` between `checkout` and `#file#`?

Result: `git checkout -- hello.c`

Comment: If you have an unfortunate branch that is named `file_I_want_discard_my_change` or `hello.c` as MindTooth said,
this step would be confused as an instruction to switch
to that branch. You should instead write:
`git checkout -- hello.c # with --